How to set tags on components of a GameObject in Unity UI?
I am trying to be able to identify which of several Collider2D instances I'm looking at from within a script. The basic idea is that I have a Sprite with three Collision2D components. Each of these is intended to detect and respond to collisions with different types of surfaces in the game. I have tagged these other surfaces sprites in the editor with their corresponding identifiers. Now I want to tag the Collider2d components on my player object. This is so that when I retrieve the Collider2D objects in my script, I can tell which Collider2D instance I'm looking at by way of the tag property. I can then make them interact with these surfaces differently.
The problem is that the unity editor seems to hide these values form me in the inspector. I can only ever assign a tag to an entity which exists in the Hierarchy list. If I add a component to the Hierarchy, then add some child component to said component (think adding a sprite, then adding a Box Collider 2D to that sprite), the inspector window does not expose the tags for the child item.

You can see in the picture above that I have selected Player from the Hierarchy list. In the inspector view you can see a couple of Box Collider 2D components which I've attached to the Player GameObject. You'll also note that there exists no way to modify the tag associated with the Box Collider 2D. The only thing I can change here is the tag associated with the Player GameObject.
I'm confused as to why this isn't available in the editor. It very clearly is from within an attached script. I can retrieve an instance of the Collider2D instance(s) from the player with GetComponents() and I can see they have a tag property however, I cannot modify the tag from within the UI. I would rather not have to use their positions relative to the Player object in a script to update the tag. This seems like a design time property I should be able to set. Is this possible?

I use additional generic Dictionaries (of key and object reference) or dictionaries of dictiories (dynamic parent->> child relationships), static and otherwise, to build different hierarchies that are not easily handled by the "base" structure. It's really not that expensive; and can untangle things by having, in effect, dynamic models.

If you look at the document, you will find that this tag property represents the tag of this game object. You need to create child game objects under the rigidbody, add colliders and set layer for each game object separately.

So is the tag property of the Collider2D object not the same as the tag of a GameObject?

It is the same as the tag of a GameObject.

Do you mean 'the same' as in in principal, or in value? I'm really struggling here, and I apologize. I'm very new to unity. I have a sprite, which via the 'Add Component' button in the Inspector window, I've added a couple of Collider2Ds. When I select the player object in the Hierarchy view, I get the Inspector for the Player sprite. In the list of components therein, I find the collider objects I added. When I select them, the UI does not allow me to modify their tag property. I can only modify the parents tag.

I mean they are associated with the same value. If you change the tag of a component, the tag of the game object will also be changed. Actually what you want is called compound colliders

Thank you, this answers my question. It's not that intuitive, but I suppose components of a GameObject inheriting the parents tag could sorta make sense. It's a bit ambiguous given that child GameObjects could have unique tags as compared to their parent. That being said, I don't generally understand the distinction between Components of a GameObject and Child GameObjects of a GameObject. I'll get there.
